# Регулярное выражение С#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

В строку записываются данные, необходимо обрезать до 150 символов, скорее всего используя регулярку.

Comment: String.Substring?

Comment: str = str.Length > 100? str.Substring(0, 100) : str; Нашёл такое решение, но не учитывает пробелы...

Comment: У вас в вопросе нет ничего о пробелах. Как именно они должны учитываться?

Comment: Сорян, всё ок, спасибо

Comment: Регулярка? Ну вот: `.{0,150}`. только это очень медленно.

Answer (score 7):

```
var str = "тут текст длинной в 150 символов";
var newStr = str.Substring(0, 149);
```

Comment: str = str.Length > 100? str.Substring(0, 100) : str;
 Нашёл такое решение, но не учитывает пробелы...